# sql union order

Tags: sql, mysql, union

I have a table students with names and heights. I want a query that order students higher that 150cm alphabetically and students smaller than 150cm in descending order of their names.

Something like this:

```
(select * from students where height >= 150 order by name)  
union 
(select * from students where height < 150 order by name desc)
```

it's not working because union mess up the order of the rows in subqueries. I know it's normal, union output a set and in a set the order it's not important. Is there something like append?

Comment: The query example is valid on MySQL.  If it's not working, provide more detail -- like the error number & message if you are getting one.

Comment: He's not complaining that it's not *running*, just that it's not returning the results he wants.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the expected output? It is a little confusing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8):

```
   SELECT *
   FROM students
   ORDER BY IF(height >= 150, 1,0 ) DESC, 
            IF(height >= 150, name, '') ASC, 
            name DESC
```

sample output

```
+------+--------+
| name | height |
+------+--------+
| a    |    189 |
| m    |    666 |
| thy  |    166 |
| yyy  |   1277 |
| zz   |    101 |
| swq  |    122 |
| n    |    111 |
| g    |    145 |
+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, case when height >= 150 then 1 else 0 end as tallstudent 
from students order by tallstudent, name
```

Comment: +1, very close and on the right track, but it won't order the short students descending

Comment: in fact my 1st half of the query it's having only one row, I want to push in front of the table one row based on its id all other rows alphabetically sorted by some other attribute

Comment: my real scenario is something like this: select *, case when id != 5 then 1 else 0 end as prio
from drivers order by prio, name

Comment: You should put your real scenario in the question body so the answer is appropriate. I don't think this query actually works for the question as you phrased it, so if you wind up accepting it because it works on your project it will be misleading to others.